# How do I know an array contains all zero(0) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array. I need to generate an alert if all the array items are 0.
For example,

```
if myArray = [0,0,0,0];
then alert('all zero');
else
alert('all are not zero');
```

Thanks.

Comment: Loop through it and return false when you run across a non-zero?

Comment: In ECMA5 you can use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use either `Array.prototype.every` or `Array.prototype.some`.

## `Array.prototype.every`

With `every`, you are going to check every array position and check it to be zero:

```
const arr = [0,0,0,0];
const isAllZero = arr.every(item => item === 0);
```

This has the advantage of being very clear and easy to understand, but it needs to iterate over the whole array to return the result.

## `Array.prototype.some`

If, instead, we inverse the question, and we ask "does this array contain anything different than zero?" then we can use `some`:

```
const arr = [0,0,0,0];
const someIsNotZero = arr.some(item => item !== 0);
const isAllZero = !someIsNotZero; // <= this is your result
```

This has the advantage of not needing to check the whole array, since, as soon it finds a non-zero value, it will instantly return the result.

## `for` loop

If you don't have access to modern JavaScript, you can use a `for` loop:

```
var isAllZero = true;

for(i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
  if(myArray[i] !== 0) {
    isAllZero = false;
    break;
  }
}

// `isAllZero` contains your result
```

## RegExp

If you want a non-loop solution, based on the not-working one of [@epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello):

```
var arr  = [0,0,0,"",0],
    arrj = arr.join('');
if((/[^0]/).exec(arrj) || arr.length != arrj.length){
    alert('all are not zero');
} else {
    alert('all zero');
}
```

This will return "all zero" if the array contains only `0`

Comment: `+1`, though I would use `false` and `true` instead of `0` and `1` but that's probably just a matter of opinion.

Comment: In case of all items are Number, and using `some`, instead of `item=>item` we can use `Boolean` for better performance. `![0,0,0,0].some(Boolean)`

Answer (score 8):

Using ECMA5 [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
function zeroTest(element) {
  return element === 0;
}

var array = [0, 0, 0, 0];
var allZeros = array.every(zeroTest);

console.log(allZeros);

array = [0, 0, 0, 1];
allZeros = array.every(zeroTest);

console.log(allZeros);
```

Comment: @Andy Added a fail test

Answer (score 4):

Using `Math.max` when you know for certain that no negative values will be present in the array:

```
const zeros = [0, 0, 0, 0];  
Math.max(...zeros) === 0; // true
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to loop, simple join and reg expression will work.

```
var arr = [0,0,0,10,0];
if((/[^0]/).exec(arr.join(""))){
    console.log("non zero");
} else {
    console.log("I am full of zeros!");
}
```

---

Another slow way of doing it, but just for fun.

```
var arr = [0,0,0,0,10,0,0];
var temp = arr.slice(0).sort();
var isAllZeros = temp[0]===0 && temp[temp.length-1]===0;
```

Comment: Clever.  Curious how it would perform against the simple `for` loop.

Comment: This cannot distinguish between `0`, `"0"`, and `[0]`

Comment: @E_net4 if that is the case, join with a "," and change the reg exp. I assumed that other slots would be numbers.

Comment: @epascarello Fair enough, it depends on the context. Regardless, it will always make a non-strict comparison with 0. Still a cool trick to watch.

Comment: @MikeChristensen For Loop will blow this away, especially on smaller arrays.

Comment: @MikeChristensen There isn't going to be a comparison, imagine jamming a 2MB array into this regex.

Answer (score 3):

> Use an early return instead of 2, 3 jumps. This will reduce the complexity. Also we can avoid initialisation of a temp variable.

```
function ifAnyNonZero (array) {
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    if(array[i] !== 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can give a try to this :

```
var arr = [0,0,0,0,0];
arr = arr.filter(function(n) {return n;});
if(arr.length>0) console.log('Non Zero');
else console.log("All Zero");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
!parseInt(myArray.join(''))
```

If your array is empty, it will return true. This is how it works:

1. Array is joined to form a string
2. Array is converted to integer
3. Integer is negated

When a zero is negated, it becomes true, because it's falsy.